# How to call a module dynamically in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Assume I have two modules **a.erl** and **b.erl**. Both modules contains the same functions ( in Java I would say "both classes implement the same interface" ).
In module "c.erl" I want to have a function that will return module "a" or "b" ( depends on the parameter )

Here is what I want to have in module **c.erl**

```
-module(c)

get_handler(Id) ->

 % if Id == "a" return a

 % if Id == "b" return b

test() ->

 get_handler("a"):some_function1("here were go for a"),

 get_handler("a"):some_function2("aaaa"),

 get_handler("b"):some_function1("here we go for b")
```

How can I make this work? I am relatively new to Erlang and don't know how to do it. In Java it would be very obvious, because you just return new instance of the class.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this question by the way it is written. Would you not just import as so: -`import(Module, [Function1/Arity, ..., FunctionN/Arity]).` and then call `a:some_function/arity` or `b:some_function/arity`?

Comment: i don't want to have different calls in module "c" or "if" statements. I want to have the same code that will call functions depends what get_handler returns. In my example get_handler chooses between "a" and "b", but there might be much more modules that it can choose from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just have `get_handler/1` return the module name as an atom, and then use it to call the desired function:

```
(get_handler("a")):some_function2("aaaa"),
(get_handler("b")):some_function1("here we go for b").
```

Note that you need parentheses around the call to `get_handler/1` in this case.

A simple version of `get_handler/1` for modules `a` and `b` could be:

```
get_handler("a") -> a;
get_handler("b") -> b.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's exactly what i need. My issue is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

If you have an atom in a variable you can use it as a module name.

So, you could define `c:get_handler/1` like this:

```
get_handler("a") -> a;
get_handler("b") -> b.
```

Your `c:test/0` looks ok, except you need extra brackets, like this:

```
test() ->
    (get_handler("a")):some_function1("here were go for a"),
    (get_handler("a")):some_function2("aaaa"),
    (get_handler("b")):some_function1("here we go for b").
```

Then in modules `a` and `b` just define a `some_function1/1` and `some_function/2`, for example:

```
some_function1(Str) ->
    io:format("module ~s function some_function1 string ~s~n", [?MODULE, Str]).

some_function2(Str) ->
    io:format("module ~s function some_function2 string ~s~n", [?MODULE, Str]).
```

**Edit:** You should possibly also define a behaviour if you're going to do this sort of thing BTW, which would mean you would declare in modules `a` and `b` something like this:

```
-behaviour(some_behaviour).
```

Then create module `some_behaviour` something like this:

```
-module(some_behaviour).
-callback some_function1 (String :: string()) -> ok .
-callback some_function2 (String :: string()) -> ok .
```

This means any module like `a` and `b` that declare that they support the behaviour `some_behaviour` must define those functions, and the compiler will speak up if they don't. The types of the parameters and return value are also defined here for static analysis, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's exactly what i need. My issue is resolved.